# How to give slide left animation in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**HTML**

```
<div class="team_line">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p ng-click="add_con()" class="add_button">Add</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="showModal">
    <p>Add Connection</p>
    <p ng-click="add_con()" class="cancel_button">Cancel</p>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.showModal = false;
$scope.add_con = function(){
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
};
```

Here I can show hidden div using angularjs. When I click on add button, I need to show hidden div slide left from right window. How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `angular-motion` [library](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-motion/). It provides many animation feature that you can apply to modal, popovers etc. using the library, here is something you can do to slide the modal from left:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-animation="am-slide-left" bs-modal="modal">
    Open the Modal
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ngAnimate` module from Angular, information [on it is here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).

ngAnimate adds `.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave` classes allowing you to animate as you please.

And [here is where you can](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#animations) find specifics of ngAnimate and ngShow together.